# app.js:3524 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined at Object../node_modules/three-bmfont-text/index.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use Three.js with three-bmfont-text to create text in 3D and give it a nice look using shaders.

I install three and three-bmfont-text through npm and import it in JS file:

```
                import * as THREE from 'three';
                const loadFont = require('load-bmfont');
                const createGeometry = require('three-bmfont-text');
```

I run npm run dev and npm run watch and everything seems to work fine, but in chrome developer it logs the following error :

app.js:3524 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/three-bmfont-text/index.js

I tried to install and uninstall three and three-bmfont-text but nothing changes, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps somebody who finds this question. This one quite popular in google.

You need to add this in webpack ([link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/frameworks/react/npm+three-bmfont-text)):

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      THREE: 'three'
    })
  ]
```

If you are using next ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65833291/load-bm-font-in-react-three-fiber-and-nextjs)):

```
config.plugins.push(
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  THREE: 'three',
 })
)
```