# Load bm-font in react-three-fiber and NextJS

Tags: reactjs, three.js, bitmap, next.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to get bitmap fonts working in react-three-fiber on a NextJS app but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it working. This is the package I'm trying to use: https://github.com/Jam3/three-bmfont-text

As you can see, both of the required packages `three-bmfont-text` and `load-bmfont` use CommonJS `require()` syntax which to be honest has always given me nothing but trouble when using NextJS. I went down the path of trying to use this in `getServerSideProps` since that only runs on the server, but that only runs in the `pages/` folder, which I need this in a global canvas component. Also, I don't think that was the right idea.

I also found a three-bmfont package for react-three-fiber but it threw encoding errors when trying to import the PNG file for the font texture. I had no idea how to troubleshoot this, so I decided maybe that package was not the answer.

I'm sure there is a way to do this and I apologize for maybe a slightly opinionated question, but I have went down a few paths that led me nowhere in how to implement this and I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`three-bmfont-text` expects a global `THREE` object. You can provide it like this in `next.config.js`:

```
config.plugins.push(
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  THREE: 'three',
 })
)
```